# How to translate "estimate" (statistics)

Tags: choix-de-mot, mathématiques, science

Je traduis un texte d'introduction aux statistiques de l'anglais au français. Deux termes très commun sont (mes definitions)

- Parameter: The true value of a population
- Estimate: The value that we estimated from the data. Good estimate are likely close tot he true value and are unbiased.

En français, "Parameter" peut être traduit par "Paramètre". Je suis tenté de traduire "Estimate" par "Estimation" mais je ne suis pas très sûr. Que pensez-vous?

En particulier, j'aimerais que vous considerez la traduction de cette phrase

> A confidence interval for an estimate of a mean gives a range of the most plausible values of the true mean.

Je traduirais par

> Un intervalle de confiance pour une estimation de la moyenne exprime l'ensemble des valeurs plausibles pour la vrai moyenne

Que me suggérez-vous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pour "**paramètre**", c'est bien ça.

On dit classiquement en statistiques "un **estimateur** de la moyenne" (ou d'un autre paramètre) pour désigner formellement cette valeur. "Une estimation" est une bonne façon de le décrire, donc n'est pas faux en tant que tel et peut être employé dans le langage courant, mais le terme consacré et la bonne traduction de "estimate" est estimateur. [Source : les statistiques sont un des volets de mon métier.][Référence à titre d'exemple : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimateur_(statistique) ]

> A confidence interval for an estimate of a mean gives a range of the
>   most plausible values of the true mean.

Je te propose:

> L'intervalle de confiance d'un estimateur de la moyenne donne une gamme des valeurs les plus plausibles de la moyenne réelle.

D'autres formulations sont possibles, mais attention à un point particulier de ta phrase, la traduction "l'ensemble des valeurs plausibles" est fausse: un intervalle de confiance définit (comme exprimé dans la version anglaise) une gamme de valeurs qui sont les plus plausibles, mais "l'ensemble" en français a un sens d'exhaustivité qui n'est pas correct dans ce contexte.

De façon plus générale, il peut être assez compliqué de traduire de la documentation scientifique ou technique, notamment en statistiques où beaucoup de termes ont un sens un peu différent de leur sens commun. Je te conseille de te référer à des documents rédigés directement en français (je cite ici Wikipédia, mais de nombreux cours sont accessibles sur internet avec une recherche basique) pour confronter les termes et formulations.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Je ne comprend pas bien quelle est la difference entre 'gamme' et 'ensemble'. L'ensemble peut être définit comme tout nombre réelle entre entre les deux limites (bound) de l'intervalle

Comment: Ici, "gamme" c'est la traduction littérale de "range". Pour "ensemble" il y a une distinction en français entre "un ensemble de [quelque chose]" , indéfini, (par exemple, un ensemble de valeurs) qui veut dire "un certain nombre de" ("a series of values", "a bunch of values", mon anglais est limité mais ça donne une idée!), et "l'ensemble des valeurs", défini, qui veut dire "toutes les valeurs". Dans ta phrase, "l'ensemble des valeurs plausibles" se traduit en anglais par "all of the plausible values", ce qui n'est pas le sens recherché - et pas le sens correct mathématiquement ;)

Answer (score 1):

Dans un premier temps, si tu souhaites conserver le terme *vrai*, je l'accorderai au féminin ce qui donnerai:

> la **vraie** moyenne.

Mais je pense que dans ce cas là, et d'après mes souvenirs de cours de statistiques, j'utiliserai le terme *réelle*, ce qui donne:

> Un intervalle de confiance pour une estimation de la moyenne exprime l'ensemble des valeurs plausibles pour la moyenne **réelle**.